# Cannot loop through videos and play (using onended event)

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I am having issues getting the video i have to loop through various movie files using the `onended event`.

I have a javascript array of video paths, such as:

```
var videos=["test.mp4","newtest.mp4","finaltest.mp4"]
```

I have a function as shown:

```
var vidcnt=0;

function runvideo()
{
    var path = videos[vidcnt];
    //alert(path);
    video=document.getElementById("splashvideo");
    vp = document.getElementById("ss");
    vp.setAttribute("src",path);
    video.play();
    vidcnt++;
}
```

And finally here is my html:

```
<video id="splashvideo" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" onended="runvideo();">
  <source id="ss" src="somefile.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

**It seems to only loop through the same video and never uses the new videos in the video array**

Comment: What is purpose of using `<source>` element?

Answer (score 0):

Use `src` at `video` element, call `.load()` within `runvideo` at `canplay` event call `.play()`

```
<video id="splashvideo" 
       controls="controls" 
       autoplay="autoplay" 
       onended="runvideo(this);" 
       oncanplay="this.play()" 
       src="somefile.mp4" 
       type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```
var vidcnt = 0;

function runvideo(video) {
    var path = videos[vidcnt];
    video.setAttribute("src", path);
    video.load();
    vidcnt++;
}
```